# Number of possible configurations in a Turing Machine

Tags: turing-machines

While studying for an up-and-coming exam, I stumbled upon the following question:

$$
L=\{\langle M \rangle,\langle w\rangle:M\text{ is single-tape and }M \text{ running on }w \text{ doesn't go over the first }|w|+1 \text{ cells} \}
$$

True or False: $L\in$$RE\setminus$$R$

The answer is false, since $L\in$$R$. The explanation was that you could write a TM $D$ that works for $(|Q|+|\Gamma|)^{|w|+2}$ steps. If during this number of steps $D$ went over the first $|w|+1$ cells, it rejects, and accepts otherwise.

I couldn't for the life of me figure out why that bound was chosen.

Any insight on the matter will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(|Q|+|\Gamma|)^{|w|+2}$ is just a crude estimate of the number of possible configurations the machine can be in without having left the first $|w|+1$ cells.

I'm assuming that $Q$ is the set of machine states and $\Gamma$ is the tape alphabet (it may be the other way around, but that doesn't matter).

In order to count configurations, we need to ask ourselves how we can *describe* a configuration. Clearly we need to tell what the contents of the tape is, which is a string of $|w|+1$ elements of $\Gamma$. But we also need to say *where* in the tape the machine is currently located, and which *state* it is in. Suppose we indicate that by writing the current state of the machine just to the left of the symbol currently being scanned. (This assumes that $Q$ and $\Gamma$ are disjoint, which can easily be arranged, or just imagined).

But that means that we now have a string of $|w|+2$ symbols taken from $Q\cup\Gamma$. Most such strings are not valid configurations, however: to be a configuration there must be exactly one symbol from $Q$ and the rest must be from $\Gamma$. But for the purposes at hand it *doesn't matter* whether we get too high a count -- the important thing is that we get a finite (and computable) one. So for simiplicity we'll just count the non-configuration strings anyway. And then the *total* number of strings we're considering is $|Q\uplus \Gamma|^{|w|+2}$.

A tighter estimate would be $|\Gamma|^{|w|+1}\cdot |Q| \cdot (|w|+1) $, but that takes more space to write, and doesn't really matter when we're only after an existence proof.

Comment: It all makes sense now, thank you!